# Docusaurus: command not found when running npm run start to host the server

Tags: docusaurus

npm run start

> balboa@0.0.0 start
> docusaurus start

sh: docusaurus: command not found

This is what shows when trying to follow the guide on how to run the local development server.
Any ideas?

Comment: Share your package.json file and hope you did npm install before doing npm run?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install the packages. Do:

- `npm install`
- `npm start` or `yarn start`